# How to make sure the user of a shiny app is using the right package versions in R

Tags: r, shiny, package

Due to recent experience with several bugs created by updating packages, I wonder what the best approach is for the following problem:

I currently provide a stand alone version so to say of my shiny App (just the script files to run it locally) and run a long list of require() functions to load / install the needed packages. However, in the end I would like to use fixed package versions to avoid bugs created by changes in packages.

Is there a way to ensure that the user, who may have older or newer versions of packages on their computer, is using the right version of all the packages my app needs?

Comment: See if `?packageVersion` helps you. I guess you can have a pkg_version table in `global.R` against which you can compare the user's package versions and update some global variable that'll talk to `server.R` and provide some message to the user when app is launched.

Comment: I think running shiny in Docker should solve this kind of problems. https://www.bjoern-hartmann.de/post/learn-how-to-dockerize-a-shinyapp-in-7-steps/

Comment: Here is a very good explanation of what docker does and how it solves your problem: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-dockerize-an-r-shiny-app-part-1-d4267659312a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using `packrat`: https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/.

> Unfortunately, private libraries don’t travel well; like all R
>   libraries, their contents are compiled for your specific machine
>   architecture, operating system, and R version. **Packrat lets you
>   snapshot the state of your private library**, which saves to your
>   project directory whatever information packrat needs to be able to
>   **recreate that same private library on another machine**.

**Short tutorial:**

1. RStudio - File - New Project - New Directory - New Project - "Do: use Path" - Create Project
2. Enter in the R(Studio) console:

Code:

```
packrat::init() 
.libPaths() # test if libpath has changed
install.packages("reshape2") # installs within one of the packrat libpaths
Installing package into ‘C:/R/packRatTest/packrat/lib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/3.4.3’
```

Assumption would be that you can use and share RStudio Projects, but i think it would be hard to work without them anyway ;).

Comment: did you try packrat @Mark?

Comment: I will try to look into it when I get the chance to do so time wise. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your shiny app as a package. You can, somewhat, control that through the description file.

Since you said you're using script take a look at: https://github.com/chasemc/electricShine
Even of you don't use it, hopefully looking at the code will help for things like setting the download repo to be a specific MRAN date.